# Scaling Vector images

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm starting out in Adobe Illustrator and I've been asked to create a 78cm by 200 cm pull down poster.  I started the project putting the exact width and height dimensions, but the computer had a hard time processing it due to the size I think, and I have an i7 computer...so I think that I'm not doing something right....

Can I for example start with a smaller version in Illustrator maintaining the ratio say 7.8cm x 20.0cm since the design would be scalable and how do I save it so that the printers could print the design for the exact 78cm x 200cm?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can absolutely work in a smaller scale, especially if you are working in all vectors. Watch if you are using any raster effects (drop shadows etc.) they don't scale as nicely. As long as everything is vector it will scale quite nicely. Any images or effects, just watch the resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem with large dimensions in Illustrator.  I can create an image that size, fill it all over with vectors, and there are no problems, and I'm using a crappy office PC at work just now - certainly nothing fancy.

However if you are using a raster image in the poster, the problem might be because the raster image is too large.  If so, did you resample the raster image to make it huge????  Large posters/banners can be printed at 72 dpi. If you resampled the raster image to full size at 300dpi - that's probably what your problem is.

Many often make this mistake when it comes to large format printing. Resampling images to 300dpi for massive prints is not required. Large format prints are generally best viewed from a comfortable distance and therefore a lower DPI setting for the raster components is usually just fine - unless you are making the poster for people to inspect with a magnifying glass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly friend, illustrator has some limitations to work with big dimensions files, so just do it in the proportions as you thought.

You can use 10:1 (7,8cm x 20cm)

Just to be clear, work in proportions is important to be sure about the resolution of the images used, in your case as your are working only with vectors, it is not a problem.